# Acumatica PXselector, how to type new value into selector control

Tags: acumatica

My DAC DMSRouteSetting.CS

```
#region RouteCD
        public abstract class routeCD : IBqlField { }
        [PXDBString(15)]
        [PXDefault, PXUIField(DisplayName = "Route ID", Required = true)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search4<DMSRouteSetting.routeCD, Aggregate<GroupBy<DMSRouteSetting.routeCD>>>))]
        public virtual string RouteCD { get; set; }

  #endregion
```

I want to select a exist value in selector or typing a new value.
Current. I just select a exist value but can't typing a new value
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding ValidateValue = false in your selector attribute

```
public abstract class routeCD : IBqlField { }
[PXDBString(15)]
[PXDefault, PXUIField(DisplayName = "Route ID", Required = true)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search4<DMSRouteSetting.routeCD, Aggregate<GroupBy<DMSRouteSetting.routeCD>>>), ValidateValue = false)]
public virtual string RouteCD { get; set; }
```

Comment: If there is a SubstituteKey, it seems like not working.

Comment: substituekey is different as you are not storing the entered value. You will most likely need to implement something that defines the ID if you are trying to create a new ID depending on the setup of your selector and DAC

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, you cant directly add new values to selector, but you can set a property to show an icon next to selector which helps to open the Master Page and user can add it there.

Look for the property
AllowAddNew="True"  AllowEdit="True"

[image]

Comment: I mean value of this selector not saved in another table.