# Saving a value in a selector that doesn't exist in the selector's choices

Tags: acumatica

I have a selector that I want to be able to either select the values that are available within the selector or just type in my own value, even if it doesn't exist in the DB, and save that text value to the column storing the selector's selection. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered here:  [Acumatica PXselector, how to typing new value into selector control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911603/acumatica-pxselector-how-to-typing-new-value-into-selector-control/34192173#34192173)

adding ValidateValue = false in your selector attribute will do the trick

Comment: I tried to find that solution and typed everything I could think of into Google but just couldn't find it! I knew it was a simple solution. Thanks a ton Brendan!

Comment: No problem. I searched "ValidateValue" to find the answer but that might have been cheating as I know what I am looking for :)  your post still might help others who search key words which did not work for you.