# How can I enter a value in a Selector that doesn't exist in the selection values

Tags: acumatica

I have to ask this question, because the solution in this case (using ValidateValue = false) didn't work for me:

[Acumatica PXselector, how to type new value into selector control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911603/acumatica-pxselector-how-to-type-new-value-into-selector-control/34192173#34192173)

Here's my selector

```
    public abstract class sourceAccount : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<sourceAccount> { }

    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Source Account")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Account.accountID,
                       Where<Account.active, Equal<True>>>),
                typeof(Account.accountCD),
                typeof(Account.description),
                SubstituteKey = typeof(Account.accountCD),
                DescriptionField = typeof(Account.description),
                ValidateValue = false)]
    public virtual Int32? SourceAccount { get; set; }
```

When this is compiled and deployed, I still get this:

[image]

Any idea why this wouldn't work for me?

The trace of the error:

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you look at the Trace information?

Comment: I added the trace to the main question.  Doesn't really tell me anything.

Answer (score 0):

First simplify selector logic:
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<Account.accountID>), ValidateValue = false)]

Then lookup all references to `sourceAccount` / `SourceAccount` to check for additional validations.

And make sure the value entered matches at DAC and DB side.
You are entering a string value when the DAC field is an integer, that will not work.

Comment: The substitute key is what takes care of entering a string when the underlying DAC field is an integer.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: After a little trial and error, I found that if I switch the selector and DAC to a string field and just use the Account.accountCD and Account.description, the ValidateValue option works as expected.  I'm assuming that if I use the Acumatica magic of the SubstituteKey (which allows a string value in the UI field even though the underlying field is an integer), the ValidateValue option doesn't work.  Correct?

Comment: If you make the field a PXDBString value the Substitute key will not work. If you make the DAC field a PXDBInt field while the database field is a NVARCHAR field then validate value will not work. You probably can't have the best of both worlds here.

Comment: A possible solution is to add a FieldUpdated event on 'AccountCD' and manually fetch and set the 'AccountID' field value if it exist. Also keep in mind that adding a new 'AccountCD' without matching 'AccountID' could introduce some corruption. It depends how the other part of the system will use AccountID/AccountCD.

Comment: The substitute key is what takes care of entering a Int value when the UI control value is a  string and the DB field is an integer.